# Citrus Framework example for oauth

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, citrus-framework

I would like to understand how to use oAuth to authenticate a REST services in Citrus Framework. I am looking for examples. Please share if you have one. It will be great if you could provide examples for both oAuth 1.0 and 2.0.

I use the below piece of code in Rest Assured to authenticate for a rest service,

```
   String ConsumerKey="yL*************a";
   String ConsumerSecret="Fig*************************aG";
   String Token="1********7-wU*************aNU";
   String TokenSecret="dhmXk******************E";

   public Response response;

   public String baseURL="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses";
   public RequestSpecification requestSpec;

   requestSpec=RestAssured.given().baseUri(baseURL);
   requestSpec.auth().oauth(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, Token, TokenSecret).queryParam("status", "I am tweetiing using rest api");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Citrus you'd have to add the headers required for the authorization via the fluent API. It should look similar to this but I haven't tested it locally.

```
        http()
        .client(myClient)
        .send()
        .post("/myOauthEndpoint")
        .header("Authorization",
                "OAuth oauth_callback=\"http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fsign-in-with-twitter%2F\",\n" +
                "              oauth_consumer_key=\"cChZNFj6T5R0TigYB9yd1w\",\n" +
                "              oauth_nonce=\"ea9ec8429b68d6b77cd5600adbbb0456\",\n" +
                "              oauth_signature=\"F1Li3tvehgcraF8DMJ7OyxO4w9Y%3D\",\n" +
                "              oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",\n" +
                "              oauth_timestamp=\"1318467427\",\n" +
                "              oauth_version=\"1.0\"");
```

The information I've used is from http://oauthbible.com/.

I'd recommend to wrap the header generation in a utility function like:

```
    http()
        .client(myClient)
        .send()
        .post("/myOauthEndpoint")
        .header(generateOauthHeader(consumerKey, consumerSecret, token, tokenSecret));
```